# Need help with Calculus " Sandwich Problem "

Tags: calculus

> Zach, feeling famished, is devouring a dazzling cheese sandwich on wheat bread which is $M$ yards by $M$ yards, but finds eating the crust to be loathsome. In order to avoid the foul, charred edges of his sandwich, he will only eat the portion of the sandwich that is closer to the center than to the edge. What percentage of his sandwich will he eat?

My teacher for Calculus gave me this problem. I've had 2 different solutions, one where the area eaten was a square of length M/2, and another where it was a circle of radius M/4, but they are both wrong due to my misinterpretation of the question. In neither attempt did I actually use anything from calculus. I simply can't answer this question by myself and need help.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, let's place the sandwich on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(0,0)$ as the sandwich center. Now let $P = (x,y)$ be some point in the sandwich.

You can for simplicity assume that $0 < x,y < M/2$, placing this point in the first quadrant, but will have to go back and see if you can symmetrically apply the argument later.

1. What is the distance from $P$ to the center?
2. What is the distance from $P$ to the boundary?
3. When will $P$ be eaten?
4. Compute the proportion of such points $P$ to the total area of this quarter sandwich.
5. Generalize the argument to other quadrants.

Comment: @RossMillikan +1, of course, corrected

Comment: Might even be simpler if you consider eighths of the sandwich.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mde9bE5HUw) for a variation of the problem.